# call javascript function from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I inherited some javascript code. One of them is a function chg(x) which reloads the page after a drop down list's value has been changed.

How do I use jquery to change the drop down list's value and call chg(x) when the value is changed ?

Comment: At the end of the day all jQuery is doing is defining a bunch of functions in JavaScript.  It's not like it's a separate language, it's just a library.

Answer (score 1):

Use the .change method:

```
$('#myDropdownID').change(function() {
  $(this).val('some value'); //will change the dropdown's selected value to whatever you want
  chg(x);
});
```

Assuming that the chg() function is somewhere in the code.

More references here: [.change() jquery method](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call `chg` anywhere where it's valid to call a function, since jQuery *IS* Javascript.

If `chg()` doesn't work, then provide us with some code specific to your situation, because it may not be defined in global context or scope such to call it like that.